# How to add HTML code to D3 tree chart at node?

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js

I'm using [D3.js tree charts](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033)

Here, I want to add HTML code to show more data and apply anchor link on each text "**tickets**" and "**events**".

[This is my jsbin](https://jsbin.com/wecexix/edit?js,output)

I'm expecting result should be shown in an image, add text like "**tickets**" and "**events**" and apply anchor link on that text

[image]

You can see that image, that tells what I expecting. I want to append text like that and add an anchor link on it. each node has 2 texts as I mentioned in this image.

Here my code

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tree-container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay{
    background-color:#EEE;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font-size:10px; 
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.templink {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.ghostCircle.show{
    display:block;
}

.ghostCircle, .activeDrag .ghostCircle{
     display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
 node.select('text')
            .attr("x", function(d) {
                return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
                return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
            })
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.name;
            }).html(function(d) {
                return "<p>"+d.name+"</p>";
            });
```

if you need a full code please [go here](https://jsbin.com/wecexix/edit?js,output)

Comment: Is the data you will pass to the tree going to contain the tickets, events, and links that you want to attach to the nodes? For example: var data = { name: 'foo', events: 10, tickets: 20, link: 'bar', children: [{...}] }

Comment: In this code, I didn't added, But I'll add that data

Comment: I'll pass that data.  if I found the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never worked on anything that required me to use urls in an svg object before, so I'm not sure if the way I implemented it is the most efficient/correct. I would be interested in knowing if there is a more correct way to do this.

So here's a codepen of what I believe you wanted:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WKrKmq?editors=0011

Building off of the code you provided from the [d3.js collapsible tree bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033), I started by populating the treeData with the following properties; 'events', 'tickets', and 'url'. After that it was pretty simple:

```
    nodeEnter.append('text')
        .attr('x', function(d) {
          return -15;
        })
        .attr('y', function(d) { 
          return 11
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return 'tickets - ' + d.tickets;
        })
        .on('click', function(d) {
            window.location = d.url;
        })
        .style('font-size', '6px');    

    nodeEnter.append('text')
        .attr('x', function(d) {
          return -15;
        })
        .attr('y', function(d) { 
          return -5
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return 'events - ' + d.events;
        })
        .on('click', function(d) {
            window.location = d.url;
        })
        .style('font-size', '6px');
```

I also increased the seperation between nodes here:

```
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .separation(function(d) { return 5; })
    .size([viewerHeight, viewerWidth]);
```

Comment: Or shall we make onclick function?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? It works fine for me. It won't actually load a new page in codepen because codepen blocks that, but if you run it locally it will work fine, i.e. if codepen loads a white page when you click the text it is working.

Comment: Awesome! Happy to help.

Comment: @siddharthaesunuri If this has answered your question, please could you accept it :), or is there something else needed?

Comment: Hi @REEE, Can you help me how can I create a pop title in mouseover instead of       text

Comment: @siddharthaesunuri Is this what you were looking for? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BPKEXy?editors=0010

Comment: Exactly True!! But how can I apply click on that tickets and events

Comment: Hi @REEE Can you explain how can I apply onclick on that text

Comment: @siddharthaesunuri I invited you to a chatroom so we can continue our conversation without commenting here, go to this link: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176351/room-for-reee-and-siddhartha-esunuri

Comment: @REEE what is the need of a function if the return value is just a constant?

Comment: @rioV8 That's not my code, that's his/the bl.ocks. I didn't bother changing it. The relevant bit is the 'window.location = d.url' and the data population in the first few lines of codepen. I only included the rest so it was easier for him to locate in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to hard code an SVG with the tags you want?
Normal HTML tags are not allowed inside an SVG tag. Just add the text like the tree node text and make them clickable.

What you need to do is at the point where you create the circle with the text and the `.on('click', click);` inside the `g.node` create two new `g` elements, one contains the circle and text and has the `.on('click', click);`. In the other add your new text elements and also make them respond to a `.on('click', textClick);`.

Comment: Can you please give an example